# Contar elementos con misma fecha fuera del bucle inicial en Javascript

Tags: javascript, bucle-for

Mi problema es:

- tengo un bucle que recorre una matriz para efectuar una operación sobre un atributo numérico de cada fila (supongamos que para la fila Y, la operación devuelve X)
- el resultado que devuelve el bucle (para cada fila) depende de las veces que esté repetido el valor fecha de esa fila en toda la tabla; es decir, el resultado del bucle para la fila Y = X / nº de veces que se repita la fecha de la fila Y en la tabla.

En mi código, tengo un bucle anidado que va mirando elemento por elemento y para cada elemento, vuelve a recorrer la tabla con el fin de contar las repeticiones de la fecha en otras filas.

Problema: las tablas que manejo son enormes y el tiempo de computación es enorme también por eso de recorrer la tabla tantas veces. Mi idea era guardar (fecha, nº de rep) antes del bucle... pero no se me ocurre cómo.

```
 for (var obs in "Tabla1")
        {
            var counts = 1;
            var month_org = BS.getmonth();
            var id =obs.id;
            var year_org = BS.getyear();
            var X = sBaC.get(year_org + "_" + month_org);
                
        
            //Check if there are more obs in the same month/year 

            for ( var obs2 in "Tabla1" WHERE obs2.id != id)
            {
                var month_mil = BS.getmonth();
                var year_mil = BS.getyear();
                if (month_mil == month_org && year_mil == year_org)
                {
                    counts ++;
                }
            }

            //Update the value for each row

            obs.valor = X/counts;               
        }
```

Comment: Buen día, el valor de meses y años es numérico, texto o tipo 'date'?

Comment: Puedes mostrar que hay en las variables month_org y year_org?

Comment: Hola! month_org, year_org devuelven un valor numérico. Lo mismo pasa con month_mil, year_mil. En el caso de los meses: enero=1, febrero=2,... (no devuelve 01, 02,... en el caso de meses < octubre =10)

Comment: Gracias, también puedes mostrar Tabla1? Cuando hagas una pregunta es mejor poner toda la información de una sola vez, así es más fácil que alguien te responda

Comment: Tabla1 tiene muchas filas (> 10000), donde cada fila es una actividad. En las columnas aparecen la fecha de realización (date), el nombre de la actividad (string), la duración (en horas, numérico), y el proyecto al que pertenecen (string). Gracias :)

Answer (score 0):

Buen día,

Podrías utilizar dos objetos para contar los meses y los años, luego recorrer toda la tabla y dentro de cada objeto se crean valores para contar el número de repeticiones en cada mes y año

```
var count_months = {};
var count_years = {};
for (var obs in "Tabla1")
{
    count_months[BS.getmonth()] = (counts[BS.getmonth()] || 0)+1;
    count_years[BS.getyear()] = (counts[BS.getyear()] || 0)+1;              
}
```